# Select single value from sphinx MVA

Tags: sphinx

I'm currently using Sphinx MVAs (Multi Value Attribute) for indexer performance reasons, each MVA only has a single value. I'm basically using the MVA's in the same way as a `sql_joined_field` (I can't use `sql_joined_field` since you cannot filter by joined values).

I want to be able to sort by the value of the MVA. According to sphinx docs, you cannot actually do this, however, you *can* sort by selected derived values. (eg, `MAX(price) AS sort_field` or `GROUP_CONCAT(tag) AS sort_field`)

Is there a way to select a single value from the MVA (or possibly concatenating all values in the MVA)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, while it **appears** you can sort by a MVA,

```
sphinxQL>select id,bucket_id from gi_stemmed where match('bridge') order by bucket_id desc;
+---------+-----------+
| id      | bucket_id |
+---------+-----------+
| 4135611 | 492       |
| 4135609 | 492       |
| 4132078 | 492       |
| 4130626 | 492       |
| 4117904 | 492       |
| 4114632 | 490       |
| 4087884 | 490       |
| 4087786 | 490       |
| 4087767 | 490       |
| 4087010 | 490       |
| 4086927 | 490       |
| 4086920 | 490       |
| 4086125 | 490       |
| 4083465 | 761       |
| 4081812 | 491       |
| 4081713 | 490       |
| 4065533 | 490       |
| 4065427 | 490       |
| 4065338 | 490       |
| 4065321 | 490       |
+---------+-----------+

Server version: 2.2.1-dev (r4133)
```

ie no error. It doesn't work completely. There are a few results out of order (see 2/3rds down in the example above)

But there is a `GREATEST()` function, which works like MAX in your question.

```
sphinxQL>select id,bucket_id,greatest(bucket_id) as two from gi_stemmed where match('bridge road') order by two desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can sort by MVA's...

```
sphinxQL>select id,bucket_id from gi_stemmed order by bucket_id desc;
+---------+-----------+
| id      | bucket_id |
+---------+-----------+
| 4138739 | 492       |
| 4138708 | 492       |
| 4138671 | 492       |
| 4138663 | 492       |
| 4138661 | 492       |
| 4138615 | 492       |
```

bucket_id is a MVA (for a similar reason to you)

```
sphinxQL>describe gi_stemmed like 'bucket_id';
+-----------+------+
| Field     | Type |
+-----------+------+
| bucket_id | mva  |
+-----------+------+

Server version: 2.2.1-dev (r4133)
```

Comment: According to the docs, this is not the case...  http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/manual-2.1.7.html#mva "That is useful to implement article tags, product categories, etc. Filtering and group-by (**but not sorting**) on MVA attributes is supported."

Comment: I guess the docs must be outdated. The above example is from a live server. I use such sorting in 'production'.

Comment: Hmm, this has been nagging at me, so ran some more tests, while it **appears** to work, its not completely exact. There are some out of order results. But there is a GREATEST (or LEAST!) function, that should work :)

Comment: What version was GREATEST() added? I'm trying to find it in the docs and can't find it. With 2.0.4 I get "parse error: unknown identifier 'greatest' (not an attribute, not a function)"

Comment: Found it...  "GREATEST()
GREATEST(attr_json.some_array) was introduced in version 2.2.1-beta. First argument is JSON array and return value is the greatest value in that array. Also works for MVA."

I doubt I'll be able to use the beta since this is for a prod site.

Comment: The arbitary label beta/stable/dev is pretty meaningless. I use the above dev version on live websites. Its more about feature freezes than actual bugs.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't get to make that decision... Betas are considered off-limits for what I'm working on.